# Illegal assignment from object to string Aggregate Result

Tags: apex, trigger, aggregate

I am getting an "Illegal assignment from object to string" on an Aggregate Result trigger.

Here is the code snipped;

```
List<AggregateResult> uniqueCountries = ([SELECT Country_Operational_Date__c FROM SBQQ__QuoteLine__c WHERE SBQQ__Quote__c IN:quoteIds 
                                                        AND country_code__c <> null AND Employee_CountFormula__c <> null GROUP BY Country_Operational_Date__c]);


            if(uniqueCountries.Size()>0 ){

                SBQQ__Quote__c quote = new SBQQ__Quote__c();

                for (AggregateResult uniqueCountry : uniqueCountries){

                    quote.Operational_Start_Date__c = uniqueCountry.get('Country_Operational_Date__c');
```

This is the line that's causing the exception,

> quote.Operational_Start_Date__c =
>   uniqueCountry.get('Country_Operational_Date__c');

How do I go about solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this lines

```
quote.Operational_Start_Date__c = String.valueOf(uniqueCountry.get('Country_Operational_Date__c'));
```

**NOTE**: Please handle Null Pointer case in your code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code , you made need field aliasing as well:

```
List<AggregateResult> uniqueCountries = ([SELECT Country_Operational_Date__c countryDate FROM SBQQ__QuoteLine__c WHERE SBQQ__Quote__c IN:quoteIds 
                                                        AND country_code__c <> null AND Employee_CountFormula__c <> null GROUP BY Country_Operational_Date__c]);


            if(uniqueCountries.Size()>0 ){

                SBQQ__Quote__c quote = new SBQQ__Quote__c();

                for (AggregateResult uniqueCountry : uniqueCountries){

                    quote.Operational_Start_Date__c = String.valueOf(uniqueCountry.get('countryDate '));
```